# How to use pthreads in order to perform simultaneous operations on an array with constraint?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I'm using pthreads in C in order to perform two operations on an `int` array: one operation doubles the value of a cell, the other operation halves the value of the cell. If after doubling a cell its value will become greater than the max allowed value the thread needs to wait until another thread will halve the value of that cell. The way I initialized the array is that the first 5 cells have value that is very close to max allowed and the other five have a value far from the max.

I decided to use a global mutex and condition variable for this. In the `main` first spawn 10 doubler threads then another 10 halver threads. But then my program freezes. I can't understand what the problem is, any help is appreciated.

My motivation is to better understand pthreads and condition variables.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ntsid.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX 20
#define THREADS_NUM 10
#define OFFSET 10

typedef struct myStruct {
    int cellId;
} myStruct;

int * cells;

pthread_mutex_t globalMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t globalCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

pthread_t threads[THREADS_NUM * 2];

void * DoublerThread(void * arg) {
    myStruct * myStr = (myStruct *) arg;
    int id = myStr->cellId;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = globalMutex;
    pthread_cond_t condition = globalCond;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while((cells[id] * 2) > MAX) {
        printf("Waiting... id = %d\n", id);
        pthread_cond_wait(&condition, &mutex);
    }
    cells[id] *= 2;
    printf("new val = %d, id = %d\n", cells[id], id);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * HalverThread(void * arg) {
    myStruct * myStr = (myStruct *) arg;
    int id = myStr->cellId;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = globalMutex;
    pthread_cond_t condition = globalCond;
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    cells[id] /= 2;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&condition);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void initMyStructs(myStruct ** myStructs) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < THREADS_NUM * 2; i++) {
        myStructs[i] = (myStruct *) malloc(sizeof(myStruct) * 2);
        if(!myStructs[i]) {
            printf("malloc error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        myStructs[i]->cellId = i % THREADS_NUM;
    }
}

void initCells() {
    int i, tmp;
    cells =(int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(!cells) {
        printf("malloc error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(i = 0; i <= THREADS_NUM; i++) {
        if(i < THREADS_NUM / 2) {
            cells[i] = MAX - 1;
        } else {
            tmp = cells[i] = 1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    myStruct ** myStructs;
    initMyStructs(myStructs);
    initCells();

    //create 10 Doubler threads
    for(i = 0; i < THREADS_NUM; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, DoublerThread, (void *) myStructs[i]);
    }
    //create 10 Halver threads
    for(i = 0; i < THREADS_NUM; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i + OFFSET], NULL, HalverThread, (void *) myStructs[i + OFFSET]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < THREADS_NUM + OFFSET; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example, by giving the array init and then show the arrays content repeatedly over time? You could also explain a little about why you want this,it might help understanding your side requirements and thereby make helping you easier.

Comment: @Yunnosch I added the motivation for the problem, not sure what you mean "array init", I have a function `initCells`.

Comment: Give an example of the arrays values and how it develops over time under the influence of the threads you describe.

Comment: @Yunnosch in my code there's an example of a possible array, `cells` array. If you take a look at the code you'll see that its first half values are 19 the second half is 1 (also described in the OP). there're `printf` statements that print new values of some of the cells, but you can't see a lot of different values because the program freezes very quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have made “private” mutexes and condition variables for each thread, so they are not synchronizing in any (meaningful) way.   Rather than this:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = globalMutex;
pthread_cond_t condition = globalCond;
```

Just use the globalMutex, and globalCond -- that is what you actually want.

[
I moved this in here, because I think we are supposed to.  I can't intuit SO-iquette.
]

> By the way, just to make sure I understand this, the mutex is per
>   cell, so that multiple threads can work on multiple cells
>   simultaneously, right? Just not two threads on the same cell. –

So, what you probably want is something more like:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
    int cellId;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t  wait;
} myStruct;
```

and in InitMyStruct():

```
myStructs[i]->cellId = i % THREADS_NUM;
pthread_mutex_init(&myStructs[i]->lock, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&myStructs[i]->wait, NULL);
```

and in Halvers:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&myStr->lock);
cells[id] /= 2;
pthread_cond_broadcast(&myStr->wait);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&myStr->lock);
```

and Doubler:
...

```
   pthread_mutex_lock(&myStr->lock);
    while((cells[id] * 2) > MAX) {
        printf("Waiting... id = %d\n", id);
        pthread_cond_wait(&myStr->wait, &myStr->lock);
    }
    cells[id] *= 2;
    printf("new val = %d, id = %d\n", cells[id], id);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&myStr->lock);
```

> So currently, only one thread can make changes to the array at a time?
>   But then the program exits after about a second, if threads couldn't
>   be making changes to the array simultaneously then wouldn't the
>   program take 10 seconds to finish, because each HalverThread sleeps
>   for 1 second. – Yos 6 hours

The Halvers sleep before grabbing the mutex, thus all sleep near simultaneously, wake up, fight for mutex and continue.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I was confused that `pthread_mutex_t` local varible "points" to the global one (because it's a struct), but now I realize I'd have to use an explicit pointer to do that. Confused by Java.

Comment: 'Confused by Java.’ -- aren’t we all :)

Comment: By the way, just to make sure I understand this, the mutex is per cell, so that multiple threads can work on multiple cells simultaneously, right? Just not two threads on the same cell.

Comment: For that, you would want either an array of mutex+condvar, or some other way of relating them to the cell.  The critical thing is that the only defined way to ensure both threads use the same mutex is for them to use the same address for the mutex structure.  Copies might work on some implementations, but not all.

Comment: So currently, only one thread can make changes to the array at a time? But then the program exits after about a second, if threads couldn't be making changes to the array simultaneously then wouldn't the program take 10 seconds to finish, because each `HalverThread` sleeps for 1 second.